# Adding the numbers of characters in a record (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I need to add the number of characters that there are in each of records.

```
SELECT 
 CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl1) +
 CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl2) +
 CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl3) +
 CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl4) +
 CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl5) +
 CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl6)
FROM mytable;
```

The above code is not valid because if a field contains NULL values then it returns NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) Control Flow Function.

```
IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
```

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl1), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl2), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl3), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl4), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl5), 0) +
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl6), 0)
FROM mytable;
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using IFNULL, like so:

```
IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(fiedl1), 0) ...
```